# Storing filter criteria in database

Tags: java, json, database, database-design

I have an web application with Javascript based UI and Jersey based REST service. The UI has certain features requiring complex search criteria to retrieve the data. The UI defines the search criteria with various parameters but the most significant to this discussion is this. A user can create a filter like this-

```
 1. (     Receiver_Email_ID           CONTAINS         xyz@abc.com                  AND

 2.       Sender_Email_ID             CONTAINS         blocked@abc.com         )    OR

 3. (     Origin_Domain                  IS            BADDOMAIN.com                AND

 4.       Email_has_attachment           ==            true                    )
```

The numbers 1 to 4 just indicate that these are different rows in the UI and that the sequence matters here. The UI represents it in JSON format which on the server could be received as a POJO. 
I need the ability to store this criteria such that the UI can be repopulated with the filter and it could be executed. Along with several other tables, I plan to use the following database table to store this-

```
rule_id
rule_seq
op_paren
left_opr
operator
right_opr
cl_paren
and_or
```

Does it look right or I can improve it? The other option I have is to store the entire JSON in an embedded document DB such as OrientDB.

Comment: Hi, can you explain it better? Thx

Answer (score 0):

From formal point of view each search criteria is [Abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) It's don't fit you structure. You idea about saving search in OrientDB is very fit to task from this point of view but realization not simple.